# Buscar informações de duas tabelas para fazer um formulário de edit

Tags: php, sql

Boa noite, fiz um formulário de cadastro de produto no qual, quando cadastro um produto, eu tenho o botão para adicionar um acessório junto. Montei o banco com as tabelas (pd_products e pd_accessories). Na tabela de produtos, coloquei a chave estrangeira de acessorios no qual vinculo um acessório em um produto. No formulário de cadastro de produtos, fiz puxar todos os acessórios para vincular ao produto mas não estou conseguindo (no formulário de edit) buscar essa informação.
O que eu estou tentando fazer é um botão que busque todos os acessórios e que tenha como "selecionado" o acessório que está vinculado no produto ao qual quero fazer alteração.
Eu sei que parece simples mas está alem das minhas capacidades de iniciante.
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Cadê o código jovem?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score -2):

Faz um INNER JOIN para pegar os dados das duas tabelas:

`SELECT L.Nome_Livro AS Livros, E.Nome_editora AS Editoras
FROM tbl_Livro AS L
INNER JOIN tbl_editoras AS E
ON L.ID_editora = E.ID_editora
WHERE E.Nome_Editora LIKE 'M%';`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).